# Wix: How to remove comment in XML file

Tags: wix

I have the following config file in my application:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <!--Setting for user name-->
        <add key="wcf:userName" value="wcfuser" />
        <!--Setting for password-->
        <add key="wcf:userPassword" value="abcdef" />

        <!--Setting for is cloud application-->
        <add key="IsCloudApplication" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
<configuration>
```

I want remove this comment on the production server via Wix XmlConfig. I tried to use the following code:

```
<util:XmlConfig Id="RemoveWcfComments" File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Web.config" Action="delete" ElementPath="configuration/appSettings" VerifyPath="&lt;!--Settings for user name--&gt;" Node="element" On="install"/>
```

,but this is not working: exceptions no occurs, but the comment remains in the config file. Any ideas?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure but you can try this:

```
<util:XmlConfig 
    Id="RemoveWcfComments"
    File="[INSTALLFOLDER]Web.config"
    Action="delete"
    ElementPath="//configuration/appSettings"
    VerifyPath="//configuration/appSettings/comment()"
    Node="value"
    On="install"/>
```

[As you can see](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/xmlconfig.html) `ElementPath` and `VerifyPath` are [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)-s, so they are invalid in your code. I'm not sure that `Node="value"` is right option, you could try `Node="element"` too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code with option Node="element", it works, but it removing only first comment in appConfig section. Other comments were left. I don't understand, why. Incidentally, the XPath configuration/appSettings also works correctly in my case.

Comment: @user3485596 well, then you should update your question with sample with multiple comments. Anyway using this a starting point you could try investigate how to remove all of the comments by yourself.

Comment: I updated the sample with multiple comments. After running the code, I get the following lines:

add key="wcf:userName" value="wcfuser" />
<!--Setting for password-->
<add key="wcf:userPassword" value="abcdef" />
<!--Setting for is cloud application-->
<add key="IsCloudApplication" value="true" />

I tried to insert the same line of code to remove the next comment, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xpath the Comment() method will select all the the comments underneath AppSettings, if you have multiple comments but want to delete only one, then make use of the xpath below:

```
VerifyPath="//configuration/appSettings/comment()[.='Settings for user name and password']"
```

If there are multiple comments and you want to delete the first comment based on the order then you can make use of the below xpath as well:

```
VerifyPath="//configuration/appSettings/comment()[1]"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried your code VerifyPath="//configuration/appSettings/comment(), but he removed only first comment in appSettings section